# Help with wiring three switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light

I am trying to wire three single pole light switches. Previous person removed middle switch and capped off the wires (I believe only the two yellow ones which is a black wire and a beige/white wire)

Confused because of the two yellow wires going into one black wire. Any advice on sorting this out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The two yellow wires on one black is okay.  they just used one hot to power two switches.  The problem seems you seem to have conduit and with conduit a white wire must be neutral.  Checking the wire colour behind those yellow wire nuts is important.  Any colour besides white or green is good, but those two wires might be on a different breaker.  Make sure there is no power.

Comment: Thank you! I see it so much more clearly now. And many thanks for the warning about the possibility of it being on another breaker. Under the two yellow wire nuts is a white wire (left) and a black wire (right) I am thinking this is the hot and neutral for the middle switch (which has been removed)

Comment: If it was cable then it would be probably okay to use the white wire on a switch, known as a switch loop.  I was told recently that white must be neutral in conduits, so thinking someone goofed up, but too important to suggest repeating a mistake.  Do you know what the third switch controlled?  checking the wiring on it might help(with picture).  Switches do not use neutral(smart switches exception).  With cable white can be marked for other use.

Comment: That makes sense. All the other wiring in the house that I’ve seen is also conduit and has been black for hot and white for neutral. The third switch controlled the light post out front. Again thank you!